# Bootstrap Validator Form Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jqbootstrapvalidation

Below is my code, both modal and javascript controlling the form. The validation doesnt work. It returns whether or not the validation requirements have been met however on submitting nothing happens. I have the jquery and bootstrap links in another file. I am using laravel 4. 
Friends using the same validator have it working but there is no difference in execution of our codes.

If i remove the validator, the form works in the constructed fashion. I have literally no idea whats going on here. Any and all help would be appreciated.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.1/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.1/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>

<head>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Style_sheet.css" type="text/css" /> -->
    <title>The Transformers</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="/title_icon2.jpg">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- // <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script> -->
</head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/docs.min.js"></script>

        <div class="modal fade" id="login_popup" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"><!--Login Popup-->
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content form-horizontal" role="form">

                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                        </button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title text-inverse" id="myModalLabel">Login</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-body form-group">
                        <form method="post" class="form-horizontal" id="login_form" action="{{ URL::route('account-login-post') }}" role="form">

                            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="input_email" class="col-sm-3 control-label text-inverse">Username:</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <input class="form-control" id="input_email" type="text" name="user_name" placeholder="Username" {{ (Input::old('username')) ? ' value="'. e(Input::old('username')) . '"' : ''}}>
                                {{ $errors ->first('username') }}
                                </div>
                            </div> 

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="input_password" class="col-sm-3 control-label text-inverse">Password:</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <input class="form-control" id="input_password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                                {{ $errors ->first('password') }}
                                </div>
                            </div> 

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="input_remember_me" class="col-sm-3 control-label text-inverse">Remember Me:</label>
                                <div>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="input_remember_me" id="input_remember_me">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </form>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button submit" class="btn btn-primary" form="login_form">Submit</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#login_form').bootstrapValidator({
                container: 'tooltip',
                feedbackIcons: {
                    valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                    invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                    validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
                },
                fields: {            
                    user_name: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: 'The username is required and cannot be empty'
                            },
                            stringLength: {
                                min: 3,
                                message: 'The username must be more than 3 characters long'
                            },
                            regexp: {
                                regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/,
                                message: 'The username can only consist of alphabetical, number and underscore'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    password: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: 'The password is required'
                            },
                            callback: {
                                message: 'The password is not valid',
                                callback: function(value, validator, $field) {
                                    if (value === '') {
                                        return true;
                                    }
                                    // Check the password strength
                                    if (value.length < 7) {
                                        return {valid: false,
                                            message: 'It must be more than 7 characters long'
                                        }
                                    }
                                    // The password doesn't contain any uppercase character
                                    if (value === value.toLowerCase()) {
                                        return {valid: false,
                                            message: 'It must contain at least one upper case character'
                                        }
                                    }
                                    // The password doesn't contain any uppercase character
                                    if (value === value.toUpperCase()) {
                                        return {valid: false,
                                            message: 'It must contain at least one lower case character'
                                        }
                                    }
                                    // The password doesn't contain any digit
                                    if (value.search(/[0-9]/) < 0) {
                                        return {valid: false,
                                            message: 'It must contain at least one digit'
                                        }
                                    }
                                    return true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            // i give up!!  The validator is on crack :-)
        //ill try a different version of the validator then :/
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: I would also like to point out i'm very new to coding.

Comment: Please can you add your include files? jquery, bootstrap.. and did you call validate for bootstrap validator?

Comment: this is bad: include it in question, and rmeoves comments :))

Comment: Also, when the validator is doing its assessment; if all validators are met for the username then it shows as a red tick? rather than green.
(also, really appreciating the help from everyone)

Comment: but did the real problem solved?

Comment: No. It still doesnt submit. It only submits if i hit enter.

Comment: because as @user8133 said, you have to include your modal-footer in form

Comment: Awesome guys. That works now. Thank you very much. Is it possible to select more then one answer as the answer, as it was a multitude of issues?

Comment: welcome anytime, no you can't select more than one answer as best :))

Comment: Might i ask another final question then? In doing what you have both suggested (it works) but some of the css on the modal is broken.

Comment: the line break between body and footer is wider than the modal box. and i still have the red tick issue.

Comment: you can post new question but before see this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to it's very important for everyone

Comment: and since my answer did resolve your problem can you accept mine as best thanks:))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not right, include all js and css files in the head tag, and include order is critical: first include jquery library, next bootstrap, next plugin for validator

```
<head>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Style_sheet.css" type="text/css" /> -->
    <title>The Transformers</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="/title_icon2.jpg">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- // <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script> -->


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/docs.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.1/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.1/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>

</head>
```

Also you have an error in your html

```
<button type="button submit" class="btn btn-primary" form="login_form">Submit</button>
```

Must be:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" form="login_form">Submit</button>
```

Also you'd better be aware of name conflict, in the future. See for more details:
http://bootstrapvalidator.com/getting-started/#name-conflict

Comment: Thanks very much. I was aware of the name conflict. But even after making this change. I still get the same issue.

Comment: I've updated answer after you post your header code, problem resides in file import order

Comment: oh. thank you. Due to working in laravel would it be acceptable to just ctrl-c+v that into the master-layout? As i have "@include" the modal file with its js?

Comment: if you use it on every page maybe it's ok, but adding it when you need it is better

Answer (score 0):

Try to include modal-footer div inside the form.

```
                <form method="post" class="form-horizontal" id="login_form" action="{{ URL::route('account-login-post') }}" role="form">
                <div class="modal-body form-group">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="input_email" class="col-sm-3 control-label text-inverse">Username:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input class="form-control" id="input_email" type="text" name="user_name" placeholder="Username" {{ (Input::old('username')) ? ' value="'. e(Input::old('username')) . '"' : ''}}>
                        {{ $errors ->first('username') }}
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="input_password" class="col-sm-3 control-label text-inverse">Password:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input class="form-control" id="input_password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                        {{ $errors ->first('password') }}
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="input_remember_me" class="col-sm-3 control-label text-inverse">Remember Me:</label>
                        <div>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="input_remember_me" id="input_remember_me">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" form="login_form">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: Skeptical. However, having tried that, the issue still persists.

Comment: try :
var validate = function () {
{$('#login_form').bootstrapValidator({....});
}

validate();

Comment: check this [link](http://bootstrapvalidator.com/settings/#event-validator), it could help you.

Comment: the var validate hasnt worked either :(. The submission of the form works if i press enter whilst inside the password/username box after filling it out. but the submit buttons doesnt work

Comment: oh yes i think you should add the form-group class to it.

Comment: wouldn't that not really affect it though, considering the mapping of the button to the form id?

Comment: bootstrapValidator working only in condition that all of its elements are inside class="form-group" and yes the type of the button should be only submit